# Different usage of Machine Learning classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have learned several classifiers in Machine learning - Decision tree, Neural network, SVM, Bayesian classifier, K-NN...etc.

Can anyone please help to understand when I should prefer one of the classifier over other - for example - in which situation(nature of data sets, etc) I should prefer decision tree over neural net OR which situation SVM might work better than Bayesian ??

Sorry if this is not a good place to post this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is EXTREMELY related to the nature of the dataset. There are several meta-learning approaches that will tell you which classifier to use, but generaly there isn't a golden rule.

If you're data is easily separable (easy to distinguish entries from different classes), perhaps decision-trees or SVMs (with a linear kernel) are good enough. However, if your data needs to be transformed into other [higher] dimensional spaces, kernel-based classifiers might work well, such as RBF SVMs. SVMs also work better with non-redundant, independent features. When combinations between features are needed, artificial neural networks and bayesian classifiers work good as well.

Yet again, this is highly subjective and strongly depends on your feature set. For instance, having a single feature that is highly correlated with the class might determine which classifier works best. That said, overall, the no-free-lunch theorem says that no classifier is better for everything, but SVMs are generally regarded as the current best bet on binary classification.